HTTP-trigger Azure Function stops sending to Service Bus after about five minutes
I have an HTTP-trigger Azure Function app with runtime version ~4 and Python 3.9. My app is triggered by a POST request that indicates how to process the input data and for how long (it might run for hours in one invocation). It processes streaming Azure Event Hubs data and sends the outputs to the Azure Service Bus.
Here is a piece of my code that sends messages to Service Bus:
import async_timeout
from azure.servicebus.aio import ServiceBusClient


client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(
    conn_str=CONN_STRING,
    logging_enable=True,
    retry_total=3,
    retry_backoff_max=10,
    retry_mode="fixed",
)

total_send_time: float = 0
message_count: int = 0
message: Optional[ServiceBusMessage] = None

async with client:
    sender = client.get_topic_sender(topic_name=TOPIC_NAME)
    async with sender:
        message = None

        while output_queue.qsize() > 0:
            try:
                async with async_timeout.timeout(10):
                    message = await output_queue.get()
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                continue

            tick = time.monotonic()
            await sender.send_messages(message, timeout=10)
            tock = time.monotonic()
            output_queue.task_done()
            message = None

            total_send_time += tock - tick
            message_count += 1
            if message_count % 20 == 0:
                average_send_time = total_send_time / 20
                logging.info(
                    f"Successfully sent {message_count} messages to Service Bus (average send time: {average_send_time:.4f} sec)"
                )
                total_send_time = 0

The problem is, after about 5 minutes of initializing the Service Bus client (async), the messages are not transmitted to Service Bus and I get no errors/exceptions and warnings in the meantime! Within the first five 5 minutes of running the app, everything works as expected, but after that, everything in the app works correctly except for sending messages to Service Bus. Note that this happens on the cloud; when I run the code locally, it works fine without any issues. I should mention that there are no networking and firewall limitations applied to the Azure Function resource.
I checked the filesystem logs on Azure Function and found this error:
Encountered a System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException exception after 300001.013ms with message: The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 300 seconds elapsing

This is the sequence of the logs:
http://0.0.0.0:8181'./appsvctmp/volatile/logs/runtime/95819576165bdac59778b1cfad868566f03e09116048c0c4ad5d3516e6e96024.log
2024-09-24T09:14:42.276924535Z: [INFO]  Updated CA certificates
2024-09-24T09:14:44.077950242Z: [INFO]  warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[15]
2024-09-24T09:14:44.077984542Z: [INFO]        Overriding HTTP_PORTS '8080' and HTTPS_PORTS ''. Binding to values defined by URLS instead 'http://0.0.0.0:8181'.
2024-09-24T10:44:06.466821919Z: [INFO]  fail: Middleware[0]
2024-09-24T10:44:06.492710253Z: [INFO]        Failed to forward request to http://169.254.132.4. Encountered a System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException exception after 300001.013ms with message: The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 300 seconds elapsing.. Check application logs to verify the application is properly handling HTTP traffic./appsvctmp/volatile/logs/runtime/4a6c3e8d7bd7e27e90a3050994cc782ccd484a5ab6b1a7d91dc1dd71ef66ceb3.log
2024-09-24T10:48:52.067841706Z: [INFO]  Updated CA certificates
2024-09-24T10:48:55.093252187Z: [INFO]  warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[15]
2024-09-24T10:48:55.093292687Z: [INFO]        Overriding HTTP_PORTS '8080' and HTTPS_PORTS ''. Binding to values defined by URLS instead 'http://0.0.0.0:8181'.Ending Log Tail of existing logs ---Starting Live Log Stream ---

What is the problem here and how to fix it?
I understand there is a hard limit timeout on the function app HTTP response, but I didn't expect it to affect other HTTP connections like the one with Service Bus.
This is my host.json file:
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.3.0, 4.0.0)"
  },
  "functionTimeout": "-1"
}

and this is my function.json file:
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    { 
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    }
  ]
}


I think it's unlikely that your call to Service Bus is the cause of the timeout. It feels more likely that you have some other logic in your Function App that's taking a long time to complete. Please could you provide the relevant source code so we can help?

I made sure that any exception occurs related to the SB client and the line where it sends the messages (await sender.send_messages(message, timeout=10)) is captured. Also, I record the average time it takes for this line to run and log it for every 20 messages I send. Everything seems normal, with no exceptions, and no client failures, and the logs show that each message takes about 0.02 seconds (on average) to be sent.

I also added a piece of the source code as well as host.json and function.json files

I'm not sure what the output_queue is, but if that keeps getting filled then the while loop will never exit. I'm not a Python expert, and I'm only guessing, but perhaps this causes two problems: 1. the Function might never exit (see discussion below on timeout.) And 2: is there any improvement if you move the Service Bus Client creation inside the while loop?

By default the function has a maximum runtime of 5 minutes. So doing up to hours of work is not something a function is good for. Better use a web job or something like that for background work. Or create an event hub triggered function that forwards the message to a service bus.

When I set the functionTimeout parameter in host.json file to "-1", doesn't it mean an infinite runtime? I'm hosting the function on an App Service Plan.

Unfortunately Microsoft doesn't guarantee that Functions can run indefinitely. Even on a Premium App Service Plan, it's likely to be OK, but only guaranteed up to 60 minutes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1414583/time-out-issue-is-coming-in-premium-plan-for-azure

If you describe what your application is doing, maybe we can help you break it up into smaller tasks, so that you can chain together a sequence of Functions. Either using Durable Functions (albeit not in Python) or Queues. This will probably bring you other benefits too, such as resilience and resuming after an error.

The app receives streaming Event Hubs data, processes it in real-time, sends outputs to Service Bus (real-time), and ingests dev outputs into ADX (in batch, with some delay). The app is written fully async.
Even if 60 minutes is guaranteed, I can't send anything to SB after 5 minutes, and no errors/exceptions in the meanwhile! So, I have no clue to look for the root of the problem.

Few things to remember here:

Function timeout -1 does not mean infinite. Maximum timeout here is 5 minutes by default (00:05:00).
If you feel your function might take more time in execution, divide them in multiple activities and try to use Durable Functions which will help you to work  with multiple activities till your execution is complete. Here, also remember that each activity will also be having maximum timeout of 5 minutes including orchestrator functions.


Thanks. I eventually ended up using Durable Functions, and it worked like a charm.
